# Google's OAuth2 requirement that I own the domain

Tags: google-oauth

Would someone give me a brief explanation for the necessity of "owning" a domain from which a Javascript app is served that makes OAuth2 calls to a service running on App Engine? I assume this is meant to prevent some security vulnerability. I just can't imagine what, since the Javascript authenticates with the service using the client running in the user's web browser, and the auth flow makes it clear what the user is being asked to allow. What difference does it make where the page comes from?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the authentication request comes from. Your app could be running locally on the client's desktop, mobile, website, etc.

[Technical reasons]:

The endpoint that Google OAuth calls back to provide the token must be transmitted securely to an HTTPS endpoint. If you specify an HTTP endpoint the authorization request will fail. In order to setup SSL on your server you must have a registered domain name. The exception is when you are using `http://localhost/` or `http://[::1]/` for authorization via a built-in webserver.

[Legal / Political reasons]:

The key is that by owning a domain, Google also has the ability to display information about who is requesting access. This is to protect the end user from fraudulent activites. The information made available to the end user includes:

- The support email address for your website.
- Application Home Page URL.
- Application Privacy Policy URL.
- Application Terms of Service.

In some countries, you must provide written information about how you will use and protect a customer's information by law. If you do not have a website, then this part cannot be accomplished by Google, who is responsible for protecting the end user using Google Accounts for authentication.